# Do movie soundtracks video clips follow the movie's age rating?

Tags: soundtrack, content-rating, music-video

I am aware of [Are content rating criteria applied to music videos?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69445/are-content-rating-criteria-applied-to-music-videos), but I am asking specifically about soundtrack videoclips that associate with a movie.

If the movie is "approved for all audiences", does it mean that the soundtrack's video clip is "also approved for all audiences"? I care primarily about this case, having in mind movies for children.

---

The motive for this question was Beyonce's videoclip about the new non-cartoonish Lion King, a movie for kids, where in the videoclip her clothes IMHO seem a little inappropriate for kids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MPAA ratings only make a statement about what one can expect from the theatrical release of a film. It's not intended to make any statement about media which is ancillary to the film, such as music videos, trailers, or television/book adaptations, any of which may or may not even exist at the time the film itself is rated. The fact that The Lion King has a rating of PG does not necessarily mean that any other media besides the film itself is suited for a PG audience.